# Split cell based on one of two characters and copy down

Tags: vba, excel

I was just asked to split a bunch of cells that look something like this:

Before:

```
Upld for #: 16 Submit URL 
HY-Upld & Attstn for #: 17 Upload Materials
HY-Attstn, Chklst & Upld for #: 31 Upload Proofs
```

The only pattern I see is that some cells have a ‘&’ character and some cells have a ‘,’ as well as a ‘&’.  I’m trying to figure out a way to parse out lines based on the ‘&’ and ‘,’ characters.  So, my ‘Before’ can be transformed into my ‘After’.

After:

```
Upld for #: 16 Submit URL 
HY-Upld for #: 17 Upload Materials
Attstn for #: 17 Upload Materials
HY-Attstn for #: 31 Upload Proofs
Chklst for #: 31 Upload Proofs
Upld for #: 31 Upload Proofs
```

All records are in ColumnA, which probably makes this a little easier.  All I can foresee is splitting the cells, like I’m trying to do in the code sample below, and copy-down for each split, based on the two characters, ‘&’ and ‘,’.  The problem, as far as I can tell, is that I can get one character split out, but not both.

```
Dim iRow As Long, nRows As Long
Dim arr As Variant
    With Sheets("Forms_Labels")
        For iRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
            With .Cells(iRow, 1)
                arr = Split(.Offset(, 0).Value, "&")
                nRows = UBound(arr)
                On Error Resume Next
                .Offset(1).Resize(nRows).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
                .Resize(nRows + 1).Value = .Value
                .Offset(, 1).Resize(nRows + 1).Value = .Application.Transpose(arr)
                .Offset(, 2).Resize(nRows + 1).Value = .Offset(, 1).Value
            End With
        Next
    End With
```

Any idea how I can make this concept work?

Comment: Do a replace of the other character with the first, then split.

Comment: What did they ask you to split the cells by? What is the logic?

Comment: First `split` using the `#` to see what has to be done (repeatedly). Then (I would) check for occurrences of `,` and / or `&`. If found, then insert a row and remove the found element until everything before the `#` is emptied out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my approach (based on my comment above):

```
Option Base 0
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpSO()

Dim arrToDo, arrWhat
Dim strWhat As String
Dim sourceList(), resultList() As String
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long, nRows As Long

Set wsSheet = Sheets("Forms_Labels")
sourceList = wsSheet.Range("A1:A" & wsSheet.Cells(wsSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value2

ReDim resultList(0)
For iRow = LBound(sourceList) To UBound(sourceList)
    arrToDo = Split(sourceList(iRow, 1), "#")
    strWhat = arrToDo(0)
    strWhat = Trim(Replace(strWhat, "for", ""))
    strWhat = Replace(Replace(strWhat, ",", " "), "&", " ")
    While InStr(1, strWhat, "  ")
        strWhat = Replace(strWhat, "  ", " ")
    Wend
    arrWhat = Split(strWhat, " ")
    For nRows = LBound(arrWhat) To UBound(arrWhat)
        resultList(UBound(resultList)) = arrWhat(nRows) & " for #" & arrToDo(1)
        ReDim Preserve resultList(UBound(resultList) + 1)
    Next nRows
Next iRow

wsSheet.Range("A1:A" & UBound(resultList) + 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(resultList)

End Sub
```

Comment: SWEEEETTTTTT!!!  Thanks so much Ralph!!  That does exactly what I want!!!!